# How to print m2 method in class A

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to print the method in Class A in the same time
To prove there are 3 threads running in the same time

```
class A {
    int a = 10; 

    void m2() {
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void m2() {
        System.out.println("end");              
    }
}

class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B b1 = new B();
        b1.m2();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to start some `Thread`(s) to have threads running. At the moment, you have one thread.

Comment: One remark on your coding style: while `String args[]` is legal, it is unconventional. It is more common to write it as `String[] args` since the brackets influence the type of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call super.m2() in class B

```
class B extends A {
    void m2() {
        System.out.println("end");
        super.m2();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does that show that there are three threads running? I do not see an answer to the question here.